# Java Card game: my Card game removes 2 cards from the deck instead of 1

Tags: java, eclipse, object, arraylist, static

Run this code so you can play it aswell.

Rules: Guess the next it's higher or lower card. if you guessed right get a score, if you guessed wrong the game ends.

the issue is that "Deck.getCards().size()" size of the deck removes 2 cards each time. I believe that the card that I print if guessed right does show another card instead of the one I had to guess before.

Can someone see what is wrong.

Bonus question: Ace in my game is the highest value card. But I somehow managed to lose while guessing lower when having a ace (maybe this has to do with that I believe I had ace because of what I outprint) if someone can help out with this one I would be so thankfull..

package CardGame;

import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.*;

public class Game {

```
// score int
private static int score;

// currentCard : Card
private static Card currentCard;
// Next Card
private static Card nextCard;
// Scanner
private static Deck deck;

private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

// Main

public static void main(String[] args) {

    deck = new Deck();

    currentCard = deck.getNextCard();

    Game.gameTurn();
}

// get turn method
public static void gameTurn() {
    // System.out.println(Deck.getCards().size());
    score = 0;


    System.out.print("your current card is " + currentCard.getName() + " is it higher or lower? > ");

    while (true) {

        String answer = sc.nextLine();
        Card nextCard = deck.getNextCard();

        if (answer.equals("higher") && nextCard.isHigherOrEqual(currentCard)) {

            correct();
        } else if (answer.equals("lower") && !nextCard.isHigherOrEqual(currentCard)) {
            correct();

        } else {

            gameOver();
            break;
        }
    }
}

// correct method

public static void correct() {

    score++;
    System.out.println("You are right! your score is: " + score);
    System.out.println(Deck.getCards().size() + " total cards");
    nextCard = Deck.getNextCard();  
    System.out.println("your current card is " + nextCard.getName());

}

// Game over Method

public static void gameOver() {
    System.out.println("you lost");
    System.out.println("total score is " + score + "!");
    System.out.println(Deck.getCards().size() + " total cards");

}
```

}

package CardGame;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Deck {

```
// cards = Card = new ArrayList<>()
private static ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

// Deck Method
public Deck() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        String suits;

        switch (i) {
        // hart
        case 0:
            suits = "Hearts";
            break;
        // ruit
        case 1:
            suits = "Diamonds";
            break;
        // schoppen
        case 2:
            suits = "Spades";
            break;
        // klaveren
        case 3:
            suits = "Clubs";
            break;

        default:
            suits = "";
            break;
        }
        for (int j = 2; j <= 10; j++) {
            int value = j;
            String name = j + " of " + suits;
            Card c = new Card(suits, name, value);

            cards.add(c);

        }
        // add 1.3 tot 1.11

        Card jack = new Card(suits, "Jack of " + suits, 11);

        cards.add(jack); // JACK

        Card queen = new Card(suits, "Queen of " + suits, 12);

        cards.add(queen); // QUEEN

        Card king = new Card(suits, "King of " + suits, 13);

        cards.add(king); // KING

        Card ace = new Card(suits, "Ace of " + suits, 14);
        cards.add(ace); // ACE

    }
    // 1.11 shuffle cards
    Collections.shuffle(cards);
}

// getNextCard() : Card

public static Card getNextCard() {

    Card nextCard = cards.remove(0);

    return nextCard;

}

// getCards() : ArrayList <card>
public static ArrayList<Card> getCards() {

    return cards;
}
```

}

package CardGame;

public class Card {

```
// Suit String
private String suit;

// Name String
private String name;
// Value int
private int value;

// Card constructor
public Card(String suit, String name, int value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.name = name;
    this.suit = suit;

}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

// toString Method
public String toString() {

    return suit;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
// isHigherorEqual Method

public boolean isHigherOrEqual(Card c) {
    if (this.value >= c.getValue()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 99 44/100% certain that `Deck.getCards().size()` doesn't remove any cards.  But `nextCard = Deck.nextCard()` _does_.  Are you sure you wanted to deal another card at that point?  Or should `nextCard` have become the `currentCard` for the next guess?

Comment: next card should be the one you should have guessed.  example: first card is 3 of hearths(you anser higher) Correct! your next card was 5 of diamonds. ok is your next card higher than 5 of diamonds? (and so on...) I did indeed experiment some stuff with currentCard and nextCard so that's why it can be messed up. it does delete 2 cards everytime and I don't know why.

Comment: Get out your debugger and step through the execution.  Here's what you'll see.  In `main` you start by dealing a "current" card, ask user "higher or lower?".  Now **in loop**, you get user's  choice, **deal a "next" card** and see if higher or lower.  If user guessed correctly, you call `correct()`.  `correct()` prints some stuff, then **deals a "next" card**.  Now `correct()` returns and you go back to top of loop in 'main`.  Get user's choice  and **deal a "next" card**, So, two cards dealt after a correct guess, and "current" card hasn't changed.

Comment: YES, I had to replace " Card nextCard = deck.getNextCard();  " out of the loop! It did work! (did not test yet if I actually printed the guessed card & if I get ace that I should lose if I answer wronger) but I guess I will find it after some testing. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using getNextCard twice before checking the result. So it will remove 2 cards. If you want to update the current card, change the nextCard to currentCard in Correct method.

```
public static void correct() {

    score++;
    System.out.println("You are right! your score is: " + score);
    System.out.println(Deck.getCards().size() + " total cards");
    currentCard = Deck.getNextCard();  
    System.out.println("your current card is " + currentCard.getName());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove nextCard = Deck. .... from correct method.
Move

```
 String answer = sc.nextLine();
 Card nextCard = deck.getNextCard();
 System.out.println("your current card is " + nextCard.getName());
```